# Why is np.sum only showing the last element of my np.array?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code:

```
N=4
for i in range(N):
    random_array=np.array([random.random()])
    print(random_array)
print(np.sum(a=random_array))
```

When I run it, it returns:

```
[0.09264558]
[0.02441606]
[0.90380555]
[0.51249256]
0.5124925563367195
```

Why is it only returning the last entry of the array and not summing over them all? Help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That *is* the sum of all your elements. Your array only has one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because every iteration the array is overridden, I guess you meant:

```
N=4
random_array = []
for i in range(N):
    random_array.append(random.random())
    print(random_array)
print(np.sum(a=random_array))
```

Example out:

```
[0.33994599217182764]
[0.33994599217182764, 0.11622954323723345]
[0.33994599217182764, 0.11622954323723345, 0.7288062755665261]
[0.33994599217182764, 0.11622954323723345, 0.7288062755665261, 0.18166667717600626]
1.3666484881515935
```

Comment: Note that building an array with `numpy.append` in a loop is a terrible idea due to quadratic runtime - all the data has to be copied into a new array every time. (`list.append` does not have this issue.) Misuse of `numpy.append` can cause code to take days when it should have taken seconds.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes I agree, edited my answer

Comment: Okay, but now you're building a list of one-element arrays, which is really weird and still inefficient (though not as bad as `numpy.append`). It'd make more sense to build a list of floats and convert to an array at the end (if at all).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica True, yeah I agree will edit

Comment: Though I'm guessing `random.random()` is just a stand in for some more complex process.  Otherwise he could just use `random_array=np.random.random(N)` and skip the loop.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah, probably is different, edited mine